# What is the resolution of an image in ImageNet dataset?

Tags: resolution, imagenet

Does anyone know the resolution of an image in the [ImageNet](http://image-net.org/) dataset?

I'm sorry, but I couldn't find it on their website or in any of the [papers](http://www.image-net.org/papers/imagenet_cvpr09.pdf).

Comment: what about in mega bytes (MB)?

Comment: is the original 500 by 500? I see this on my end: `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=500x500 at 0x7FDB2A0ABDC0>`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The images vary in dimensions and resolution.  Many applications resize / crop all of the images to 256x256 pixels.

Comment: what about in mega bytes (MB)?

Comment: is the original 500 by 500? I see this on my end: `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=500x500 at 0x7FDB2A0ABDC0>`

Comment: What "original" do you mean?  The official ImageNet contest data, as I said, has a variety of sizes.

Comment: This is an independent question.  Please post it as such.

Answer (score 33):

The average image resolution on ImageNet is 469x387 pixels. Normally it's applied a pre-processing that samples them to 256x256 as @Prune said, but it depends on the task at hand.

Answer (score 12):

In a brief check of a random ImageNet 2012 folder (Fish)...
The largest image is 4288 x 2848 pixels.
The smallest image is 75 x 56 pixels.
This is representative of the aspect ratio range.

Answer (score 7):

It depends of the picture but you can resize them. The smaller dimension of the picture should be at least 256 px and the aspect ratio should be intact.

Comment: To both conserve aspect ratio and have the same size on all images after resizing and padding (asssuming no cropping), the larger dimension must be specified, rather than the smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

`224 X 224` is used by most of the networks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a detailed answer to this in the following article: https://towardsdatascience.com/compression-in-the-imagenet-dataset-34c56d14d463

Essentially, most common image size is 500x500, however, there is a large distribution of image sizes. Typically, either the width or the height of an image is 500 pixels, if not both. Aspect ratios of 1:1, 4:3, 3:2 (and 3:4 and 2:3) are most common.